# Why does the highest supported date for both _gmtime32 and _gmtime64 fall on January 19, in different years?

Tags: windows, time

It's well-known that signed 32-bit `time_t` will run out on January 19, 2038 (the [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).

The Windows function `_gmtime64` takes a 64-bit `time_t`, so in principle it could support a vastly larger range of dates. But, it turns out it doesn't support dates past the year 3000. Specifically, the largest `time_t` that can be successfully passed to `_gmtime64` is 32536846799, which is on January 19, 3001.

Is it just a coincidence that these two apparently-unrelated ranges both end on January 19? Why does `_gmtime64` run out when it does?

---

Python code for computing the largest allowable `time_t`:

```py
In [1]: from time import gmtime

# invariant: gmtime(low) is ok, gmtime(high) fails
In [2]: low, high = 0, 100000000000

In [3]: while high - low > 1:
   ...:     midpoint = low + (high - low) // 2
   ...:     try:
   ...:         gmtime(midpoint)
   ...:     except OSError:
   ...:         high = midpoint
   ...:     else:
   ...:         low = midpoint
   ...:

In [4]: low
Out[4]: 32536846799
```

Comment: Must be a conscious decision on behalf of some programmer... Note that while unsigned 32-bit time limit falls on some random moment in 2038 `env TZ=UTC python -c "import time; print(time.ctime(2**31))"` → `Tue Jan 19 03:14:08 2038` the limit you found calls on the end of the day: `env TZ=UTC python -c "import time; print(time.ctime(32536846799))"` → `Mon Jan 19 20:59:59 3001` 

Comment: Also for extra LOLs: setting BIOS date beyond that day completely messes up Windows: https://community.amd.com/thread/250108 so who knows, maybe they plan to fix it in the next thousand years? :)